# Как избежать раздувания таблиц (table bloating)?

Tags: postgresql, update, insert

*Иногда*, например, при большом количестве `INSERT/UPDATE` операций, размер таблицы начинает нелинейно расти. Например, в моем случае при ~6 * 10<sup>6</sup> последовательных операций `UPSERT` размер (место на диске) таблицы вырос с обычных ~200-500Mb до 8Gb. Неприятно обнаружить десяток таких толстяков вместо *нормальных* таблиц. Более того, против таких таблиц не помогает обычный `VACUUM` и, соответственно, `autovacuum` тоже бессилен, что приводит к тому, что размер БД растет втихую и *правда* открывается тогда, когда кончается место на диске. Я использую UPSERT следующего вида (и знаю про изменения в 9.5):

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET "<column_name>" = <data> 
FROM <another_table> 
WHERE <another_table>.<id> = <table_name>.<id>;

INSERT INTO <table_name> ("<id>", "<column_name>")
   SELECT "<id>", "<column_name>" FROM <another_table>
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT "<id>" FROM <table_name> WHERE "<id>"=<another_table>.<id>);
```

Что с этим всем делать? Регулярно проводить `VACUUM FULL` совсем не вариант, ибо слишком долго и неавтоматизированно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Архитектура PostgreSQL такова, что любое изменение в таблицах - это всегда новая строка на физическом уровне хранения данных. Исключение составляет команда удаления, которая только лишь маркирует удаляемую строку как уже невидимую другим транзакциям. Как именно хранятся строки на физическом уровне можно посмотреть вот здесь:

[«Что у него внутри» - хранение данных на низком уровне](https://pgconf.ru/media/2016/05/13/tuple-internals-ru.pdf)

Поэтому очень важно не делать длительных транзакций. Стараться внутри одной транзакции изменять относительно небольшое количество строк.
Поэтому если коротко, то ответ на ваш вопрос: исключить раздувание таблиц нельзя.

Так, что же делать?

1. Необходимо обязательно оставлять всегда включенным автовакуум!
   И даже более, его необходимо делать более агрессивным, чем он есть из коробки. Для этого нужно изменить настройки в postgresql.conf относительно:

> select * from pg_settings where name ~ 'autovacuum'

autovacuum = on         # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'

autovacuum_max_workers = 10     # max number of autovacuum subprocesses

autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.001  # fraction of table size before 
vacuum

autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.005 # fraction of table size before 
analyze

autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 10ms # default vacuum cost delay for 
autovacuum, in milliseconds -1 means use vacuum_cost_delay

Вот здесь можно дополнительно почитать о autovacuum

[Все, что вы хотели узнать про автовакуум в PostgreSQL](http://pgday.ru/ru/2015/papers/31)

Дополнительно, можно на уровне отдельных таблиц регулировать чувствительность автовакуума к числу удалённых строк. Это команда:

> ALTER TABLE public.mytable 
>   SET (
>   autovacuum_enabled = true,
>   autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.01,
>   autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.05 
>   );

параметры подберите экспериментально исходя из:

Задаёт процент от размера таблицы, который будет добавляться к autovacuum_vacuum_threshold при выборе порога срабатывания команды VACUUM. Значение по умолчанию — 0.2 (20% от размера таблицы). Задать этот параметр можно только в postgresql.conf или в командной строке при запуске сервера. Однако данное значение можно переопределить для избранных таблиц, изменив их параметры хранения.

2. Если всё же таблицы распухли и надо их ужать, а запускать VACUUM FULL нельзя, так как пользователи работают и блокировать их работу недопустимо, то нужно смотреть в сторону использования вот таких инструментов:

   2.1 [pgcompacttable](https://github.com/PostgreSQL-Consulting/pgcompacttable)

пример вызова для установленного ActivePerl для windows
c:\perl64\bin\perl.exe pgcompacttable.pl -h <имя сервера> -p 5432 -U postgres -W <пароль> --all --verbose info > c:\temp\pgcompacttable.log

Что делается внутри?

Если кратко то если в таблице есть свободное место то при update записи новая версия пойдет в это свободное место. 
При этом безусловное предпочтение отдается свободному месту в начале таблицы при его наличии. 
В итоге если обновлять таблицу (fake updates вида поле=поле) начиная с последней страницы в какой то момент 
все записи с последней страницы перейдут в свободное место в начале таблицы. 
Теперь если тоже самое проделать N раз то последние N страниц базы окажутся пустыми и обычный неблокирующий Vacuum 
их сможет отрезать от таблицы и освободить (vacuum без full умеет освобождать страницы в конце таблицы если они полностью свободные). 
Для прохода с конца таблицы используется доступ по tid (фактически доступ с физическим указанием номеров страниц 
и записей на страницах http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html описание поля ctid). 
Все остальное уже детали реализации и оптимизация по скорости проще посмотреть в исходниках.
Vacuum fulll делает приблизительно тоже самое вешая полный (exclusive лок) на таблицу 
и упаковывая все страницы в таблице сразу а не инкрементально по кусочкам.
Это решение заметно медленне это непреложный факт (раз 5-10 точно, если сравнивать с pg_reorg). 
Но оно инкрементальное и позволяющее лимитировать нагрузку. 
И не требующее сборки дополнительного софта на сервере.

2.2) [pg_repack](https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_repack)

pg_repack is a PostgreSQL extension which lets you remove bloat from tables and indexes, and optionally restore the physical order of clustered indexes. Unlike CLUSTER and VACUUM FULL it works online, without holding an exclusive lock on the processed tables during processing. pg_repack is efficient to boot, with performance comparable to using CLUSTER directly.